# Passport never links a user to a session

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to figure out why Passport fails initializing a user session (after logging in, `req.isAuthenticated()` always fails):

**1)** Passport never gets into `passport.serializeUser` or `passport.deserializeUser`:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback) {
    callback(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, callback) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (!err) callback(null, user);
        else callback(err, null);
    });
});
```

**2)** The local strategy I created works: `passport.authenticate` has access to the user object, and no errors are thrown:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, message) {
    // No errors here, always access to the correct user object
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

**3)** My configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(cookieParser('secret'));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
  router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');

router.use(session({
  secret: config.secrets.session,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 3600000,
    secure: (config.env === 'production')
  }
}));
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
```

After doing a POST request to `/login`, `req.isAuthenticated()` always reports negative. When checking the console, only the Express session cookie (connect.sid) is created. Logging `req.session` to the console (directly after `app.post('/login'....) {`) gives:

```
{ cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Tue Jan 27 2015 22:30:18 GMT+0100 (CET),
     originalMaxAge: 3600000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false },
  passport: {} 
}
```

I re-checked my configuration a hundred times, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you certain that you're not in the production environment as understood by your config module?

Comment: Yes, I double-checked it, but it's set to development.

Answer (score -1):

i had exactly the same problem while searching for a solution i came across this post.
your cookie is not being set i changed my session.cookie.secure to false in development and it works fine.

```
    var sess = {
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { secure: false}
    }

    if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    sess.cookie.secure = true // serve secure cookies 
    }

    app.use(session(sess))
```

Comment: The code above is already checking the environment; secure cookies are only enabled in production

Answer (score -3):

@jroeleveld, I suggest you checkout the below code and also more configure code available on http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Emile, that's exactly the code I wrote at the top of my post; can't find an error in that?